# Text: number of words containing softened/lengthened/two vowels/two consonants C++

Tags: c++

the code doesn't calculate the number of Ukrainian words, but only English ones, and only Ukrainian ones should be used.

Here is the program code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cctype>

class TextOperation {
public:
    TextOperation(const std::string& inputText) : text(inputText), wordCount(0) {}

    void displayText() const {
        std::cout << "Текст: " << text << std::endl;
    }

    void countWordsWithProperties() {
        std::vector<std::string> words;
        splitTextIntoWords(words);

        for (const auto& word : words) {
            if (containsSoftConsonant(word) || containsLongVowel(word) || containsDoubleVowel(word) || containsDoubleConsonant(word)) {
                wordCount++;
            }
        }

        displayWordCount();
    }

    void displayWordCount() const {
        std::cout << "Кількість слів, які містять пом’якшені/подовжені/дві голосні/дві приголосні букви: " << wordCount << std::endl;
    }

protected:
    std::string text;
    int wordCount;

    void splitTextIntoWords(std::vector<std::string>& words) const {
        std::string word;
        for (char ch : text) {
            if (std::isalpha(ch)) {
                word.push_back(ch);
            }
            else if (!word.empty()) {
                words.push_back(word);
                word.clear();
            }
        }

        if (!word.empty()) {
            words.push_back(word);
        }
    }

    bool containsSoftConsonant(const std::string& word) const {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < word.length(); ++i) {
            if (isSoftConsonant(word[i])) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    bool containsLongVowel(const std::string& word) const {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < word.length() - 1; ++i) {
            if (isVowel(word[i]) && isVowel(word[i + 1]) && !isDoubleLetter(word[i], word[i + 1])) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    bool containsDoubleVowel(const std::string& word) const {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < word.length() - 1; ++i) {
            if (isVowel(word[i]) && isVowel(word[i + 1]) && isDoubleLetter(word[i], word[i + 1])) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    bool containsDoubleConsonant(const std::string& word) const {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < word.length() - 1; ++i) {
            if (isConsonant(word[i]) && isConsonant(word[i + 1]) && isDoubleLetter(word[i], word[i + 1])) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    bool isSoftConsonant(char ch) const {
        return (ch == 'б' || ch == 'в' || ch == 'г' || ch == 'ґ' || ch == 'д' ||
            ch == 'ж' || ch == 'з' || ch == 'й' || ch == 'л' || ch == 'м' ||
            ch == 'н' || ch == 'п' || ch == 'р' || ch == 'с' || ch == 'т' ||
            ch == 'ф' || ch == 'х' || ch == 'ц' || ch == 'ч' || ch == 'ш' ||
            ch == 'щ');
    }

    bool isVowel(char ch) const {
        return (ch == 'а' || ch == 'е' || ch == 'и' || ch == 'і' || ch == 'ї' ||
            ch == 'о' || ch == 'у' || ch == 'ю' || ch == 'я' ||
            ch == 'А' || ch == 'Е' || ch == 'И' || ch == 'І' || ch == 'Ї' ||
            ch == 'О' || ch == 'У' || ch == 'Ю' || ch == 'Я');
    }

    bool isConsonant(char ch) const {
        return std::isalpha(ch) && !isVowel(ch);
    }

    bool isDoubleLetter(char ch1, char ch2) const {
        return (ch1 == ch2);
    }
};

int main() {
    std::string inputText;
    std::cout << "Введіть текст: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, inputText);

    TextOperation textOperation(inputText);
    textOperation.displayText();
    textOperation.countWordsWithProperties();

    return 0;
}
```

Actual output:
Введіть текст: насіння колібрі казан насіння знаряддя обличчя
Текст: насіння колібрі казан насіння знаряддя обличчя
Кількість слів, які містять пом’якшені/подовжені/дві голосні/дві приголосні букви: 0

Expected output:
Введіть текст: насіння колібрі казан насіння знаряддя обличчя
Текст: насіння колібрі казан насіння знаряддя обличчя
Кількість слів, які містять пом’якшені/подовжені/дві голосні/дві приголосні букви: 4

Comment: That Cyrillic text is going to represented as UTF-8, isn't it? E.g. if I save `Текст` into a text file, it's 10 bytes. But you're processing it using `char` (1 byte) with the assumption that each letter is 1 `char`... but they aren't.

Comment: @DanMašek I have a feeling it will be a regional ASCII, thus it's dependent on configuration of operating system's language